# deliver_later using sidekiq rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I tried to do deliver_later using sidekiq, but I got a error message.

Here is my setup

```
* execute redis
redis-server

* execute sidekiq
bundle exec sidekiq -q default -q mailers

* Gemfile
gem 'sidekiq'


* application.rb
config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sidekiq


#send email
 UserMailer.account_activation(@user).deliver_later
```

I have no idea how to resolve the problem.
Here is error message

```
50.345Z 41513 TID-oxh5ccnb8 ActionMailer::DeliveryJob JID-1c7ea4b33150d3805ff777aa INFO: start
2016-11-18T17:13:50.413Z 41513 TID-oxh5ccnb8 ActionMailer::DeliveryJob JID-1c7ea4b33150d3805ff777aa INFO: fail: 0.068 sec
2016-11-18T17:13:50.414Z 41513 TID-oxh5ccnb8 WARN: {"context":"Job raised exception","job":{"class":"ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::SidekiqAdapter::JobWrapper","wrapped":"ActionMailer::DeliveryJob","queue":"mailers","args":[{"job_class":"ActionMailer::DeliveryJob","job_id":"c2ee4092-4e73-4e1f-857f-3e081594c735","queue_name":"mailers","priority":null,"arguments":["UserMailer","account_activation","deliver_now",{"_aj_globalid":"gid://academic-lib/User/8"}],"locale":"en"}],"retry":true,"jid":"1c7ea4b33150d3805ff777aa","created_at":1479489230.323255,"enqueued_at":1479489230.3232949,"error_message":"No route matches {:action=>\"edit\", :controller=>\"account_activations\", :email=>\"chandleryang76@gmail.com\", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]","error_class":"ActionView::Template::Error","failed_at":1479489230.4132302,"retry_count":0},"jobstr":"{\"class\":\"ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::SidekiqAdapter::JobWrapper\",\"wrapped\":\"ActionMailer::DeliveryJob\",\"queue\":\"mailers\",\"args\":[{\"job_class\":\"ActionMailer::DeliveryJob\",\"job_id\":\"c2ee4092-4e73-4e1f-857f-3e081594c735\",\"queue_name\":\"mailers\",\"priority\":null,\"arguments\":[\"UserMailer\",\"account_activation\",\"deliver_now\",{\"_aj_globalid\":\"gid://academic-lib/User/8\"}],\"locale\":\"en\"}],\"retry\":true,\"jid\":\"1c7ea4b33150d3805ff777aa\",\"created_at\":1479489230.323255,\"enqueued_at\":1479489230.3232949}"}
2016-11-18T17:13:50.414Z 41513 TID-oxh5ccnb8 WARN: ActionView::Template::Error: No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"account_activations", :email=>"chandleryang76@gmail.com", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
2016-11-18T17:13:50.414Z 41513 TID-oxh5ccnb8 WARN: /Users/chandler/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/journey/formatter.rb:50:in `generate'
/Users/chandler/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:629:in `generate'
/Users/chandler/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:660:in `generate'
/Users/chandler/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:707:in `url_for'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with sidekiq don't use deliver later because the job never performs, instead use perform_in(<>) and call a worker with the method deliver_now inside

Comment: deliver_later should work with sidekiq as long as sidekiq's configured for active jobs (`config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sidekiq` -
 https://gist.github.com/maxivak/690e6c353f65a86a4af9).

Comment: @mahemoff is right! Works when setting queue adapter

Answer (score 1):

I guess you follow the book《ruby on rails tutorial》, if we run the code with deliver_now, the result will correct, but if we run the code with deliver_later, the error top will show.
After reading active job guides, i know active job use GlobalID, which makes it possible to pass live Active Record objects to your job instead of class/id pairs.

In the book 《ruby on rails tutorial》, the attribute activation_token is virtual attribute

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :activation_token
end
```

active job use user object as argument, user object will be sent as excepted, but the virtual attribute will lost, the methods are as follows:

> 1. persist the activation_token attribute or
> 2. transmit the activation_token attribute alone

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def account_activation(user, activation_token)
    @user = user
    @activation_token = activation_token
    mail to: user.email, subject: "user activation"
  end
end

UserMailer.account_activation(user, user.activation_token).deliver_later

<p><%= link_to "active link", edit_account_activation_url(@activation_token, email: @user.email) %></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the error

> 2016-11-18T17:13:50.414Z 41513 TID-oxh5ccnb8 WARN: ActionView::Template::Error: No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"account_activations", :email=>"chandleryang76@gmail.com", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]

Your mailer view is erroring out. Somewhere there you have something like this

```
edit_account_activation_path(@activation)
```

where `@activation` is nil. Hence the error. Edit path is not valid without an object.

Answer (score 0):

There is error in mailer view.
You need to check @activation object which is passing as nil.